# OEM to ansi conversion with D2009+

Tags: delphi

For the Unicode version experts:

Is it possible to define a ansistring type that reflects the current OEM encoding ?

(assuming that ansistring without codepage identifiers reflect ansi codepage)

It's half a joke question, and half serious:

It would simplify my port of the CRT unit to Unicode greatly (making it nice and typed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you should be able to use `CP_OEMCP` just as you can use `CP_ACP` to get the Ansi code page.

```
type
  OemString = type AnsiString(CP_OEMCP);
```

If that doesn't work, then declare your variable as a `RawByteString`. Fill it with the data it needs, and once you find out what the current OEM code page is (with [`GetOEMCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318114.aspx)), use [`SetCodePage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.SetCodePage) to assign that code page to the string (at which point it won't exactly be a `RawByteString` anymore, despite its declared type).

Comment: I want to declarare certain procedures to accept only OEM. And to autoconvert if necessary. The first solution is good for this and accepted, the second makes less sense (since with manual conversion steps I might as well call simply oemtoansi and back)

Comment: (note I only checked the logic, I didn't actually test it, or that multiple kinds of ansistrings are overloadable. TYPE x = type y doesn't always work for that)

Comment: Is the extra `type` keyword even necessary? If you can overload on AnsiString versus Utf8String, then you should be able to overload based on OemString, too.

Comment: I never found much use for type. It doesn't seem to help for overloading of simple types. I couldn't even come up with a piece of code in Borland Pascals where it matters I guess. But that is maybe something for a separate question

Comment: You must use `type` when declaring new `AnsiString(N)`-based types.

Comment: It matters in the declaration of `TDateTime`, @Marco. Otherwise, for example, the Object Inspector will have you edit properties of that type as an ordinary `Double` instead of showing the date-time picker. Likewise for `TColor`.

Comment: So such new defined type is only for RTTI, and not for overloading? Do you have other examples?

Comment: @Marco: `grep -r '= type ' $(BDS)\Source\\*`; I don't know how many of those *really* need the new type. I thought it was only for RTTI, but if Remy says it's required for code-page-specific AnsiString types, then I'll take his word for it; I don't have a new enough Delphi version to confirm for myself. Maybe the compiler uses the RTTI to generate the right conversion code.

Comment: ansistring is special since the types must be different to insert autoconversions. But apparantly this is prepared  for ansistring[] in the compiler, but not for other types. I prefer not to grep through Embarcadero sources for possibly FPC related purposes out of cleanroom reasons. Anyway, thanks. The RTTI reason was new to me.